# Quebra de linha no placeholder no textinput do react-native

Tags: react-native, placeholder

Existe a possibilidade de uma quebra de linha no TextInput do react native pra que ele mostre todo o placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

Sim, existe uma propriedade chamada `multiline` que permite a quebra de linha no input e o default é false, conforme podemos ver na [documentação](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#multiline).